# IPC: Connect for each request or keep socket open?

Tags: java, c++, sockets, ipc

I am planning to use sockets (local TCP) to communicate between two processes (running locally). One process will act as a server, but both processes send messages to each other asynchronously. Should I keep the socket connection open for the lifetime of the processes, or re-connect for each request?

Are there any problems that may occur if I keep a local socket open?

Comment: socket type? I'm guessing tcp/ip.

Comment: Yes. It's a local TCP socket [edited question]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Keep the socket open.**

Its the simpler option and you don't incur in the overhead of opening a new socket (from the client point of view) or accepting a new client (from server point of view).

Comment: +1. One caveat is to include message length into the protocol.

Comment: ..or use some other protocol that allows 'messages' to be sent over a streaming service like TCP.  I agree with 'Keep the socket open' - a three-way handshake before a message can be communicated, followed by a four-way termination handshake, is a great way of slowing your apps down, esp. if on different machines with a high-latency network connection.

Comment: @Nikolai N Fetissov - I would recommend the typical approach to TCP messages: human readable messages separated by a new line (CR and/or LF). [not really sure if this applies to the problem since I have no idea what he is trying to communicate].

Answer (score 1):

If it's just one client, then you should keep the socket open but be ready to reconnect in case of error (the user could have reset network interfaces for example, so connection is not guaranteed to be alive). If you have many clients, use disconnection after inactivity timeout of certain time. This will let you get rid of inactive, hung or "lost" (the ones that passed away but there was no signal about socket closing form them) clients.